# ksh if loop vs [[ ]] && { cmd1 ; } || { cmd2 ; }

Tags: if-statement, ksh

I am working on a shell script and following syntax works fine:

```
if [[ 1 -eq 1 ]] ; then
   [[ 2 -eq 1 ]]
else
   echo hi
fi
```

Debug run :

```
+ [[ 1 -eq 1 ]]
+ [[ 2 -eq 1 ]]
```

If i shrink the statement it jumps to the else condition:

```
**[[ 1 -eq 1 ]] && { [[ 2 -eq 1 ]] ; } || echo hi**
```

Debug run:

```
+ [[ 1 -eq 1 ]]
+ [[ 2 -eq 1 ]]
+ echo hi
hi
```

any ideas what is missing?

Thanks much. 
Sam

Comment: how can `1 -eq 1` and `2 -eq 1` both be true? when you chain them together, you get a false statement because `2 -NE 1`, so you get the else path. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could say the following:

```
[[ 1 -eq 1 ]] && { [[ 2 -eq 1 ]] ; true ; } || echo hi
```

if the first test passes, you go into the `{...}` block and once you run, what you wanted to run in there, by ending with `true` you do not continue past `||` here standing in for your `else` clause.

The problem is. `[[ 2 -eq 1 ]]` returned false and hence you get to your `echo hi` beyond `||`.

All that said, you may see it looks a bit ugly and in this case (esp. as multiple conditions are involved which may impact how your pipeline gets evaluated). Well, I would recommend not saving on few newlines and for sake of obvious and readable code use the longer form.

Comment: Thank you. i guess i wasnt getting the response of [[ 2 -eq 1 ]] part. this helps.

Comment: Yeah, the last return value of the `{...}` block (in this case result of the inner test) propagates out and the rest I guess is obvious..